# React redux , Why log is nan

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```js
const initialState= {
    noOfIceCream: 100
}

export const iceCreamReducer = (state=initialState, action) => { 
    switch(action.type) {
        case ICE_CREAM_BUY:
            console.log('ICE CREAM BUY case  ',state.noOfIceCream)
            return {
                ...state,
                noOfIceCream: state.noOfIceCream-1
            }
        default:
            return {
                state
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your default return statement, try this:

```js
const initialState = {
  noOfIceCream: 100
}

export const iceCreamReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ICE_CREAM_BUY:
      console.log('ICE CREAM BUY case  ', state.noOfIceCream)
      return {
        ...state,
        noOfIceCream: state.noOfIceCream - 1
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```